# concatenating string in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, concatenation

I am converting a command line to a python string. The command line is:

```
../src/clus -INFILE=../input/tua40.sq -OUTPUT=OUT
```

The python statement is:

```
c_dir = '~/prj/clus/'
c_bin = c_dir + 'src/clus'
c_data = c_dir + 'input/tua40.sq'

c = LiveProcess()
c.executable = c_bin
c.cwd = c_dir 
c.cmd = [c.executable] + ['-INFILE=', 'c_data, '-OUTPUT=OUT']
```

Problem is the `c.cmd` at the end looks like

```
~/prj/clus/src/clus -INFILE= ~/prj/clus/input/tua40.sq ...
```

Not that there is a 'space' after '=' which causes the program to report an error.

How can I concatenate '=' to the path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LiveProcess` is expecting an argv-style list of arguments.  Where you want to make one argument, you need to provide one string.  So use concatenation to make the string:

```
c.cmd = [c.executable] + ['-INFILE='+c_data, '-OUTPUT=OUT']
```

Also, no need for the list addition:

```
c.cmd = [c.executable, '-INFILE='+c_data, '-OUTPUT=OUT']
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just concatenate string like this:

```
a = 'A'+'B'
```

then

`a == 'AB'`

that is in your example

```
['-INFILE=' + c_data, '-OUTPUT=OUT']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
c.cmd = [c.executable] + ['-INFILE='+c_data, '-OUTPUT=OUT']
```

Comment: You've over-concatenated there.  "-OUTPUT" needs to start a new element.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it looks like you're concatenating paths, you should be using [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join), not regular string concat.